# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy

So, what I'm trying to do is to get certain numbers from certain positions in a array of a given > range and put them into an equation:

```
yy = arange(4)
xx = arange(5)
Area = ((xx[2] - xx[1])(yy[2] + yy[1])) / 2
```

I try to run it and I get this..

```
----> ((xx[2] - xx[1])(yy[2] + yy[1])) / 2
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable
```

I get an error.. How can I use certain numbers in an array and put them into an equation?

Answer (score 33):

Python does not follow the same rules as written math. You must explicitly indicate multiplication.

#### Bad:

```
(a)(b)
```

*(unless `a` is a function)*

#### Good:

```
(a) * (b)
```

Answer (score 28):

> This error also occurs when your function has the same name as your return value

```
def samename(a, b):
    samename = a*b
    return samename
```

This might be a super rookie mistake, I am curious how often this answer will be helpful.

Comment: python for 5 years and just made this mistake...found this answer helpful when trying to resolve it...

Answer (score 11):

You are missing `*` when multiplying, try:

```
import numpy as np
yy = np.arange(4)
xx = np.arange(5)
Area = ((xx[2] - xx[1])*(yy[2] + yy[1])) / 2
```

Answer (score 5):

This could happen because you have overwritten the name of the function that you attempt to call.

For example:

```
def x():
    print("hello world")
...
x = 10.5
...
x()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      2     print("hello world")
      3 x = 10.5
----> 4 x()

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```