# 'numpy.float64' object is not callable with numpy and pandas with custom function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vector

I have code of the form:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def StrdErr(vec):
  return np.std(vec)/np.sqrt(len(vec))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

for idx_q in range(0, df2.shape[0]):
  StrdErr = StrdErr(np.array(df2.loc[idx_q, :]))
```

with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug.py", line 11, in <module>
    StrdErr = StrdErr(np.array(df2.loc[idx_q, :]))
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

I saw a [similar question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828212/typeerror-numpy-float64-object-is-not-callable) but could not solve the problem
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have named the return value of the function the same as the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a very complicated way to compute:

```
df2.std(1, ddof=0).div(np.sqrt(df2.shape[1]))
```

output:

```
0    0.471405
1    0.471405
2    0.471405
dtype: float64
```

###### even if it is inefficient, to fix your loop use:

```
out = []
for idx_q in range(0, df2.shape[0]):
  out.append(StrdErr(np.array(df2.loc[idx_q, :])))
print(out)
# [0.47140452079103173, 0.47140452079103173, 0.47140452079103173]
```

Answer (score 1):

DavidG's comment explains the problem. This answer explains why you don't need to bother fixing it:

Generally speaking, it's safe to assume that if you ever find yourself looping over a numpy array or pandas dataframe, you're doing something wrong. These libraries are built with vectorization and broadcasting in mind -- allowing you to perform the same operation on multiple data at the same time.

If you ever find yourself looping with a numpy or pandas object, take a step back and ask yourself:

> Am I calculating a common, standard mathematical function?

- If so, try to search for it in the package's documentation -- chances are it's common enough to have been implemented (e.g., standard deviation, correleation coefficient, etc)
- If not, try to approach the problem from a vector-math perspective -- if what you're calculating in a `for` loop is a scalar equation on a single element of the array or dataframe at a time, then you can vectorize the equation to perform that operation on the entire vector at once

In this case, standard error of the mean is a common mathematical function which Pandas includes in its library as `pandas.DataFrame.sem`:

```py
df.sem(ddof=0, axis=1)
```

Take a look at the difference in performance for a `(1000, 3)` dataframe:

```py
In [3]: def StrdErr(df):
   ...:     out = []
   ...:     for idx_q in range(0, df.shape[0]):
   ...:         vec = np.array(df.loc[idx_q, :])
   ...:         out.append(np.std(vec) / np.sqrt(len(vec)))
   ...:     return out

In [4]: df.shape
Out[4]: (1000, 3)

In [5]: %timeit StrdErr(df)
118 ms ± 10.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit df.sem(ddof=0, axis=1)
453 µs ± 56.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```